# How to rotate imageview without lagging?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am integrating a compass in my app, but the problem is the image view lag while rotating it. How can i fix this issue and making it like the app of apple which rotate with a nice way?

**Here is the code that i am using:**

```
float heading = -1.0f * M_PI * degree / 180.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    self.compassImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading);
} completion:nil];
```

**Here is the compass:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXF9A.png

Comment: How often do you call this code?

Comment: Well, how often is that? With what frequency do you pull new data out of the compass? Because right now it sounds like you have multiple animations that fight against each other.

Comment: Every 1° i rotate the image view.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the animateWithDuration duration. You don't need it. I guess you want it since you want the motion to be smooth, but I have a similar app that shows roll and pitch and I just call

```
tiltImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(angle));
```

and it moves smoothly.

You're just over thinking it here. (JustSid is right.)

Comment: I did what you've just said and it's still lagging.

Comment: Try more optimizations. If you are on the same heading as last time, don't rotate at all.

Comment: Do your NSLog's lag? Meaning, do they show jumpy coordinates or are they smooth? If you took the animation completely out like this answer suggest then that only leaves the answer that you must be calling something else on the main thread(GUI) that's causing lag. Place an NSLog for your DegreesToRadians(angle) result and watch it updating.